# Upgrade install from 13/10 to 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 14.04

I had a windows 8.1 Intel based system running dual boot ubuntu 13.10.  I proceeded with upgrade made available when I logged into ubuntu.  Upgrade seemed to go OK, but upon reboot, Ubuntu was unavailable and booted to an OS type prompt with limited capabilities.  I was unable to find any documentation on how to correct.  I created a boot DVD, and am now offered on option to override windows or create an ubuntu volume.  My original volume of 40GB is identified as well as my Windows 8.1 boot partition.  Can I select the 40GB partition, FAT32, and assign /boot,and will this correct the problem.  I also read a swap partition nay be needed, is this something I need to create and how?  I want to keep dual boot capability.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Boot-Repair.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

> **Get a CD including Boot-Repair**
>   
>  The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to burn one of the following disks and boot on it.
>
> [Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home) is a CD starting Boot-Repair automatically.
>
> Boot-Repair is also included in [Linux-Secure-Remix][2].
>
> Remark : you can also install the ISO on a [live-USB][3] (eg via [UnetBootin][4]
>   or [LiliUSB][5] or [Universal USB Installer][6]).
>
> **Using Boot-Repair** Recommended repair launch Boot-Repair from either : the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen) or
>   System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
>
> or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal Then click the "Recommended
>   repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL
>   (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and
>   check if you recovered access to your OSs.
>
> If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you
>   by email or forum.